# On Measurability of Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

It is a well known fact that if $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $E$ can be written as a union of an $F_{\sigma}$ set $F$ and a measure zero set $N$: $E=F\cup N$, and the converse is also true.

I encountered a real analysis exercise that, if it were still true that $F$ is changed into merely a closed set:

If $E$ is measurable, then $E=F\cup N$ for some closed set $F$ and $|N|=0$.

I believe this is false, but cannot figure out any counterexample.

Comment: The interval $(0,1)$ good enough?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up a bit: the center issue is to look for a measurable set such that it cannot be written as a union of a closed set and a measure zero set. But then why $(0,1)$ is such an example?

Comment: Any closed (relative to $\Bbb{R}$) subset of $(0,1)$ has a least and most point, so it's contained in an interval $[a,b]$ with $a>0, b<1$.

Comment: Do you want $F$ to be relatively closed in $E$ or closed in $\Bbb{R}$?  Because if you want $F$ to be relatively closed in $E$ you can just take $F=E$.

Comment: I have got what you meant, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is essentially due to John Doe in the comment session.

The center issue is to look for a measurable set $E$ such that it cannot be written as a union of a closed set $F$ and a measure zero set $N$.

Take $E=(0,1)$. If $F$ is a closed subset (closed relatively to $\mathbb{R}$) of $(0,1)$, then it is compact. Consider the covering $\{(1/n,1-1/n)\}_{n\geq 3}$ of $(0,1)$. Then $F\subseteq(1/n_{0},1-1/n_{0})$. But then

\begin{align*}
1=|(0,1)|=|F\cup N|=|F|\leq|(1/n_{0},1-1/n_{0})|=1-2/n_{0}<1,
\end{align*}
a contradiction.